# Theano falls back to CPU

Tags: theano, lasagne, theano-cuda

I am training a model in `Theano 0.9` and `Lasagne 0.1` and want to run it on GPU. I've set `THEANO_FLAGS` as follows:

```
THEANO_FLAGS=device=gpu0,force_device=True,floatX=float64
```

Theano prints it is using GPU

```
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 980 Ti (CNMeM is disabled, cuDNN 4007)
```

However, I noticed it's not, profiling shows that it's using [CorrMM](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/conv.html) operation which is according to the docs

> CorrMM This is a CPU-only 2d correlation implementation taken from caffe’s cpp implementation and also used by Torch.

I have CUDA Toolkit 7.5 installed, Tensorflow works perfectly on GPU.
For some reason Theano is falling back to CPU, it is supposed to cause an error due to `force_device` flag but it's not.

I am not sure where the problem is as I'm new to Theano, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is floatX=float64.
Use floatX=float32. GPU supports 32 bit only yet.

Comment: Thanks! I had to use Float64 because my input data is in that format, The precision shouldn't be a big problem.